# Returning generic List without parametrized parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, generics, casting

A generic method was created in GenericService:

```
public <E> ResponseEntity<List<E>> get(String url) throws RestClientException, NotAuthenticatedException {
        ResponseEntity<List<E>> l = getClient().template().exchange(getClient().apiUrl(url), HttpMethod.GET, null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<E>>() {
                });
        return l;
}
...

ResponseEntity<List<NotificationDTO>> result = get(url);
List result.getBody(); //<--debug point
```

but it is always getting List without parametrized items to E, which should be a list of NotificationDTO at the debug point,

somebody to tell or suggest why ParameterizedTypeReference:53 have not provided a correct type?

Comment: `it always getting List without parametrized items to E` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily difficult to read sir

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: meant, that it returns List<E>, but I expected  List<NoificationDTO>, but Sotirios Delimanol has answered already practically. And flob has already answered theoretically.

Comment: @kolossus: it was made as it is to deliver the essence of the question. Any suggestion how to make it more clear for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to the **[type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)**.

At compile time all generic type information is checked, deleted and therefore not available at runtime.

The section [Problems with type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) on Wikipedia might help to understand it better.

Comment: thank you for some deeper theory and found developing "Valhalla" project under "See also" in the second link

Comment: Thanks :-) And once again I dug into the depths of Wikipedia like in the old days...

Answer (score 2):

The type token *hack* (`ParameterizedTypeReference`) works by returning the actual type argument provided to it at compile time in the source code. In your case, that is

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<E>>()
```

In other words, it's `List<E>`. And since Jackson or whatever deserializer you use doesn't know what `E` is, it uses its default types.

There's no way to use the type token dynamically with type variables. Use concrete types.